# Working with multiple PushButtons and Textboxes dynamically

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I have a program that will act as a network-linked visualizer for a hardware system with no screen (think RaspberryPi). I currently have a QTabWidget with around 45-50 QPushButtons and textboxes (for numbers), but I'm bothered by the amount of connect statements I'll have to make. Is there a better way to make this many buttons? I've seen methods for using an array, but nothing with using a QTabWidget and the only thing I saw on that was creating a form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sorry I can't give you a proper answer with code.  I have no proper internet so I have to do this on a phone.

Set up an array of buttons, maybe even a custom class derived from QPushButton with a signal that includes an identifier for the button, such as `std::string name`.  You can then run a loop assigning your connects with something like:

`connect(buttonArray[x], SIGNAL(buttonIsPushed(std::string) ), receivingObject, SLOT(buttonWasPushed(std::string)))`

Of course this may be of little help if the receiving object has to pass on the signal as a signal.